# PowerBI - Create report or query to show missing value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Trying to create a PowerBI report - I have a table below and want to filter on which stores do not have Pears.  It's very straightforward to create a report view and drill through which stores have specific fruit, but I can't figure out the opposite.

| Store | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| store1 | Apples |
| store1 | Bananas |
| store1 | Pears |
| store2 | Apples |
| store2 | Bananas |
| store3 | Apples |
| store3 | Bananas |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what your desired output is. But if you are only interested in the inadequate stores, use this DAX table measure:

```
No Pears Stores = 
EXCEPT (
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Store] )
    ),
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Store] ),
        'Table'[Fruit] = "Pears"
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thanks Peter.  Is there a way to keep the "Pears" as a variable where I can select the value? drill though?